# Compute sum of numerical values of an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array:

```
myArray = [32.4, "bla", 1.44, 0.5, 65.8, "abc"];
```

To compute the `sum` of an array containing only digits is pretty straight-forward, but how can it be done if there are also non-numerical values which must be ignored?

Comment: Check for `typeof`.

Comment: `a.filter(Number.isFinite).reduce((x, y) => x + y)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.reduce` and check if the element is number using `isNaN()`

If you want to add strings which represents a number then you can use:

```js
var myArray = [32.4, "bla", 1.44, 0.5, 65.8, "abc"];
var sum = myArray.reduce((acc, el) => acc + (!isNaN(el) ? +el : 0));
console.log(sum);
```

If you want to ignore string which represents a number `"1"` then use `typeof`

```js
var myArray = [32.4, "bla", 1.44, 0.5, 65.8, "abc"];
var sum = myArray.reduce((acc, el) => acc + (typeof el === "number" ? el : 0));
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 3):

Parse everything as numbers and check for NaN

```
var sum = 0
myArray.forEach(el => {
   if(!Number.isNaN(parseFloat(el))) sum += parseFloat(el)
})
```

This solution also works for array with strings representing numbers like ["4.5", "5", "a", 10] (will give 19.5)
If you don't want this behaviour, you'd better check with type of:

```
var sum = 0
myArray.forEach(el => sum += (typeof el == "number" ? el : 0))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function combined with [`.isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) to check if you have a Number.

```js
var myArray = [32.4, "bla", 1.44, 0.5, 65.8, "abc"];

var res = myArray.reduce(function(acc, curr){
  return acc + (isNaN(curr) ? 0 : curr);
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: try `myArray = ["1", "2", "3"]` ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array.prototype.filter` and `array.prototype.reduce`:

```js
var myArray = [32.4, "bla", 1.44, 0.5, 65.8, "abc"];

var sum = myArray.filter(n => !isNaN(n)).reduce((m, n) => m + n);

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: try `myArray = ["1", "2", "3"]`

Answer (score 1):

Use `reduce` and `isNaN`

```
var arr = [32.4, "bla", 1.44, 0.5, 65.8, "abc"];
var output = arr.reduce( ( a, c ) => a + ( isNaN( c ) ? 0 : c ), 0 );
```

**Demo**

```js
var arr = [32.4, "bla", 1.44, 0.5, 65.8, "abc"];
var output = arr.reduce( ( a, c ) => a + ( isNaN( c ) ? 0 : c ), 0 );
console.log( output.toFixed(2) );
```

**Explanation**

- Use `reduce` to initialize an accumulator `a` to `0`.
- Use `isNaN` to check if `c` (array item for current iteration) *Is-Not-A-Number* (if not add `0` to `a`)

Answer (score 1):

```
var numbers = myArray.map(value => {
    value = parseFloat(value);
    return (isNaN(value))? 0: value;
});
```

Then calculate the sum of `numbers`

Answer (score 0):

I would even combine two of the answers above and use the common **Map Reduce** strategy:

```
var numbers = myArray.map((value) => {
    value = parseFloat(value);
    if(isNaN(value)) value = 0;
}).reduce(function(acc, curr){
  return acc + (isNaN(curr) ? 0 : curr);
});
```

Of course you could press everything in Map or the reduce function, but as I was taught the Map function prepares the values in a proper form and afterwards the reduces function's goal is only to combine all the available values to a single one using a given function / strategy.

*(I'm sorry if there's a syntax error, I'm only coding in Swift atm.)*